# if / else if inside getter/setter Java

Tags: java

I recently started my education Software Engineering where we are currently learning the basics of Java... we have to create a simple text-based airport game and i ran into a little trouble.

I already tried google and the SOF search function and found many "solutions" however; none seem to fix my problem. so forgive me for my "noob" qeustion :P

In the game we have several airports that generates a random amount of passengers each round, with a minimum of 100 and a maximum of 999. To do this i used the following code... which works and doesnt give me any errors but i still get random results below 100. What am i doing wrong? like i said i tried many different ways but it seems to neglect my if / if else conditions...

```
int paxGenerator;

public int getPaxGenerator() {
    return this.paxGenerator = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);

}

public void setPaxGenerator(int paxGenerator) {

    if (paxGenerator<100) {
        this.paxGenerator = 100;
    } else if (paxGenerator > 999) {
        this.paxGenerator = 999;
    }

}
```

EDIT:

`return this.paxGenerator = (int) (Math.random() * 900) + 100;` does indeed fix my problem, thx @user43219 However, for the sake of learning; can someone give me an example of how i should correctly implement an if else statement? Because i want to create 12 new objects, that all have to generate a different random number. if i place the random code outside the getter/setters it gives me the same number everytime... and the if else statement isnt even allowed outside the getter/setters... bear in mind im a beginner so things arent that obvious to me :P thx in advance!

Comment: Try to analyse what your getter does, that's where you're going wrong.

Comment: Why does your getter generate/assign a value every time it's called, when you also have a setter?

Comment: You could look into [Random.nextInt(int n)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int))

Comment: Can you please provide a complete code?

Comment: Just an FYI - It's not good practice to put logic into your getters and setters.  Put the logic outside of the getters/setters and THEN call them.  Use getters and setters simply for assigning and retrieving data.

Comment: ` return this.paxGenerator = (int) (Math.random() * 900) + 100; `

does indeed fix my problem, thx @user43219

However, for the sake of learning; can someone give me an example of how i should correctly implement an if else statement?

Because i want to create 12 new objects, that all have to generate a different random number. if i place the random code outside the getter/setters it gives me the same number everytime... and the if else statement isnt even allowed outside the getter/setters... bear in mind im a beginner so things arent that obvious to me :P thx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a "floor" of 100 passengers, I personally would avoid all the complicated logic and just use `this.paxgenerator = (int)(Math.random()*900)+100;`

`(int)(Math.random()*x)` will generate numbers from 0 to x-1.

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling your setter.  The line:

```
return this.paxGenerator = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);
```

does *not* implicitly call `setPaxGenerator()` - it bypasses the setter and sets the property value directly.

Comment: Although this answers your question exactly, I would like to add that you should not abuse getters and setters to this extent. 
- getPaxGenerator should be idempotent, i.e. one expects the value to remain the same no matter how often you read it. 
- setPaxGenerator should set the value to exactly the value you pass it (or throw an exception if the value is invalid).
Anything else will just confuse others using your code.
In your case, just create a single method named generatePax() or something and put all your random generation code in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Random` class.

```
Random rand = new Random();

 int randomNum = rand.nextInt((999 - 100) + 1) + 100;

  System.out.println(randomNum);
```